# Segmentation fault in my C program while reading from a file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to get each line from a file and doing some string operations.  But my piece of code throws seg fault.  I tested the same thing for one line as a different program and it works fine.  But when I read from a file and do string manipulation operations it throws me segmentation fault.

Variable declarations:

```
char *pch3,str1[100],str2[100]


 pch3 = strtok(line3,",");
                        while(pch3!=NULL)
                        {
                                if(strcmp(pch3,"?") == 0)
                                {
                                       strcat(str1,"0");
                                       strcat(str1,",");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                       strcat(str1,pch3);
                                       strcat(str1,",");
                                }
                                pch3 = strtok(NULL,",");
                        }
                        strlen1=strlen(str1);
                        memcpy(str2,str1,strlen1-1);
                        fp2=fopen("breast-cancer-wisconsin-miscellaneous-cleansed.data","a");
                        fprintf(fp2,"%s\n",str2);
                        fclose(fp2);
```

Comment: Please use a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: How is str1 defined? How is str2 defined?

Comment: You should also post how str1 and str2 is declared and allocated. Plus, with a debugger you can easily find what line throws the sigsegv

Comment: Thanks :) What is the maximum length of each line?
In any case, I suggest to run the application in a debugger first to see where the SIGSEGV occurs - I suppose somewhere around the strcat() or the memcpy calls.
Additionally, please consider using strncat() instead of strcat() and make sure to properly zero-terminate str1 afterwards.

Comment: Also, if you just want to replace question marks with zeroes, just use something like `sed -e 's/,?,/,0,/g'` instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: My Prof said no to shell scripting..

Comment: Then you should add a homework tag

Comment: 1. do not use memcpy to copy strings, use strlcpy instead 2. if you do use memcpy, you need to copy the terminating 0 as well, you need to use strlen + 1, not strlen - 1

Comment: strlen-1 is to truncate the last character ,

Comment: Then that's the wrong way to do it, use strlcpy instead.

Comment: But still thats not the one causing problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialize `str1` and `str2`, which means when you use `strcat` it tries to find the end of the previous string, but that can be anywhere in `str1`, even outside `str1` if `str1` does not contain a zero.

Change the declaration to this and it should work better:

```
char *pch3, str1[100] = "", str2[100] = "";
```

Comment: @Bobby Then it might be time to bring out the debugger, to see exactly where it crashes. Also, you are sure the string you build will never be larger than 99 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't solve your current problem, please consider using stat(3) and mmap(3).  You can then process the memory region.  Alternatively you can have a loop with fgets(3)/feof(3)/ferror(3) and process each line of input.

Please initialize all buffers via memset to zero.

You can also probably do

```
char str1[100] = { 0 };
```

strcat(3) is also evil, you can try to use snprintf(3) instead, or strncat(3) if you know what you are doing.  Read the relevant man pages for further information.

Answer (score 0):

One particular detail to consider: strtok() modifies the string which you pass in as first parameter. The following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void processLine (const char *line3) {
  char *pch3 = NULL, str1[100] = "", str2[100] = "";
  int strlen1 = 0;
  FILE* fp2 = NULL;

  pch3 = strtok (line3, ",");
  while (pch3 != NULL) {
      if (strcmp (pch3, "?") == 0) {
          strcat (str1, "0");
          strcat (str1, ",");
      } else {
          strcat (str1, pch3);
          strcat (str1, ",");
      }
      pch3 = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }

  strlen1 = strlen (str1);
  memcpy (str2, str1, strlen1 - 1);
  fp2 = fopen ("breast-cancer-wisconsin-miscellaneous-cleansed.data", "a");
  fprintf (fp2, "%s\n", str2);
  fclose (fp2);
}

main () {
  char input[100] = "first,?,second,third,fourth,?";
  processLine (input);
}
```

Again, please consider using more buffer overflow safe functions like strncat() instead of strcat() and add guards or at least assertions which check buffer lengths to avoid buffer overflows.